# How to use an EventToCommand with an editable Combobox to bind TextBoxBase.TextChanged with a command?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, mvvm-light, eventtocommand

I have an editable ComboBox.

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CritereChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextBoxBase.TextChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CritereChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

I use GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.EventToCommand to bind the SelectionChanged event.
I also would like to bind the TextChanged event, but it is a little bit tricky:
This event is only accessible by the ComboBox TextBoxBase property, and I can't find the proper way to bind this event.
You can see one of my unsuccessful attempt: SelectionChanged binding works fine, but TextChanged binding does not.

I also tried this syntax:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True">
    <TextBoxBase>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CritereChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBoxBase>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CritereChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

But this won't even compile. I get an error "Type that can be instantiated expected" on the TextBoxBase tag.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a way to work around the problem:
I create an invisible TextBox, bound to the ComboBox, and I bind the command on the TextChanged event of the TextBox.
It's not pretty, but it works...

```
<ComboBox Name="CbRubrique" IsEditable="True">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CritereChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=CbRubrique, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CritereChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 5):

I know, very late response... but I hope it will help someone.

The problem here is that the `EventTrigger` class in `Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.dll` uses `reflection` to find the event by the value of the `EventName` property and this won't work for attached events like `TextBoxBase.TextChanged`.

**One option**, which I use, is to implement your own custom `EventTrigger` class as described [here](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.co.il/2009/05/mvvm-invoking-command-on-attached-event.html) and use this one instead of EventTrigger (the link there to `CommandAction` implementation is broken, but I managed to get it using internet archive).

**Another option**, which I don't like because it's not classic `MVVM Command` use, is to bind the `Text` property of the `ComboBox` to a property in the `ViewModel` and invoke the command from the ViewModel code on the setter, like this:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
          Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

And in the ViewModel:

```
private string text;
public string Text
{
    get { return text; }
    set
    {
       text = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("Text");
       if(CritereChangedCommand.CanExecute())
          CritereChangedCommand.Execute();//call your command here
    }
}
```