# Model Property not hitting Set Accessor in WPF MVVM Project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am learning and creating my first WPF application attempting to Implement the MVVM design pattern, however I cannot seem to work out why this property is not firing its Set Accessor, so I can make use of the OnPropertyChanged Method I have.  Would really appreciate an explanation as to why this is not working as I expected.

The part I do not understand is that in the GetChargeUnits method in the ViewModel I am creating an instance of my Charge Unit Model and setting the Property to be the result of the reader (This reader does return a result) The Property sets fine? But when stepping through it never hits the Set line in the property so I cannot detect if it has changed.  The part commented in this method was what I had originally I have tried many combinations.

Please help, thanks

Model:

```
public class ChargeUnit : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _chargeUnitDescription;
    private int _chargeUnitListValueId;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ChargeUnit()
    {

    }
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public string ChargeUnitDescription
    {
        get { return _chargeUnitDescription; }
        set
        {
            _chargeUnitDescription = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ChargeUnitDescription");
        }
    }

    public int ChargeUnitListValueId
    {
        get { return _chargeUnitListValueId; }
        set
        {
            _chargeUnitListValueId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ChargeUnitListValueId");
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ClientRatesViewModel
{
    private IList<ClientRates> _clientRatesPreAwr;
    private IList<ClientRates> _clientRatesPostAwr;
    private List<ChargeUnit> _chargeUnits;
    private const string _connectionString = @"connectionString....";
    public ClientRatesViewModel()
    {
        _clientRatesPreAwr = new List<ClientRates>
        {
            new ClientRates {ClientRatesPreAwr = "Basic"}
        };

        _clientRatesPostAwr = new List<ClientRates>
        {
            new ClientRates{ClientRatesPostAwr = "Basic Post AWR"}
        };

        _chargeUnits = new List<ChargeUnit>();
    }

    public IList<ClientRates> ClientRatesPreAwr
    {
        get { return _clientRatesPreAwr; }
        set { _clientRatesPreAwr = value; }
    }

    public IList<ClientRates> ClientRatesPostAwr
    {
        get { return _clientRatesPostAwr; }
        set { _clientRatesPostAwr = value; }
    }

    public List<ChargeUnit> ChargeUnits
    {
        get { return _chargeUnits; }
        set { _chargeUnits = value; }
    }

    public List<ChargeUnit> GetChargeUnits()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT LV.ListValueId, LV.ValueName FROM tablename", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var test = new ChargeUnit();
                        test.ChargeUnitDescription = reader["ValueName"].ToString();
                        //_chargeUnits.Add(new ChargeUnit
                        //{
                        //    ChargeUnitDescription = reader["ValueName"].ToString(),
                        //    ChargeUnitListValueId = (int)reader["ListValueId"]
                        //});
                    }
                }


            }

        }
        return new List<ChargeUnit>();
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked your VS settings for getters and setters? This is for VS 2013 but you probably can Google that for other versions.
Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General.
Then on the right side uncheck "Step over properties and operators (Managed only)"

Comment: @FrankJ You cracked it! Thanks a lot

Comment: @FrankJ Just realised this was part the issue, as it is jumping into the set now, when I set it in the ViewModel, however when I change the value in the combobox the ChargeUnitDescription Property in my Model never reaches the Set, however it does always return the Updated Value I have just selected?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint into the Setter code? Binding propagated changes are not easily observable while stepping through code only. You need a breakpoint. If that doesn't work post  a minimal code example that I can run in VS and describe the steps of what you are doing, what is happening and what you would expect to be happening based on the example.

Comment: @FrankJ  If you refer back to the model I posted above, there is a breakpoint in the setter of the ChargeUnitDescription.  This never gets hit, when I select any item in my combobox.  However the get gets hit everytime and the _chargeUnitDescription contains the ChargeUnitDescription displayed in the combobox.
My Xaml comboboxs displaymemberpath is also this Property (ChargeUnitDescription)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding.

Think about it that way: Why would `ChargeUnitDescription` in your Model change? You are not changing the content of that property.

What you describe is, you are changing the `SelectedItem` of your `ComboBox`. The `get` of your model instance get's hit because the `ComboBox` needs to access it to display the string as you defined it in your binding with the `DisplayMemberPath` property of the `ComboBox`.

What you are interested in is the `SelectedItem` or`SelectedValue` (depending on your setup) of the `ComboBox`.

Here is a minimal example to illustrate this:

```
    namespace SOBindingTest1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ClientRatesViewModel crvm { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            crvm = new ClientRatesViewModel();
        }


        public class ChargeUnit : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private string _chargeUnitDescription;
            private int _chargeUnitListValueId;

            public ChargeUnit()
            {

            }

            public string ChargeUnitDescription
            {
                get { return _chargeUnitDescription; }
                set
                {
                    _chargeUnitDescription = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            public int ChargeUnitListValueId
            {
                get { return _chargeUnitListValueId; }
                set
                {
                    _chargeUnitListValueId = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void OnPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler tmp = this.PropertyChanged;
                if (tmp != null)
                {
                    tmp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
        }

        public class ClientRatesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public ClientRatesViewModel()
            {
                _chargeUnits = new List<ChargeUnit>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    _chargeUnits.Add(new ChargeUnit() { ChargeUnitDescription = i.ToString(), ChargeUnitListValueId = i });
                }
            }

            protected ChargeUnit _SelectedItem;
            public ChargeUnit SelectedItem
            {
                get
                {
                    return this._SelectedItem;
                }
                set
                {
                    if(this._SelectedItem == value)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    this._SelectedItem = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }


            private List<ChargeUnit> _chargeUnits;
            public List<ChargeUnit> ChargeUnits
            {
                get { return _chargeUnits; }
                set 
                {
                    if(this._chargeUnits == value)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    _chargeUnits = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void OnPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler tmp = this.PropertyChanged;
                if (tmp != null)
                {
                    tmp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the corresponding xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="SOBindingTest1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SOBindingTest1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Text="Bla:"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10"/>
      <ComboBox Name="cboTest" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" DisplayMemberPath="ChargeUnitDescription" SelectedValuePath="ChargeUnitListValueId" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=crvm.ChargeUnits, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=crvm.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

UPDATE:

Changed the code so it fills the selected item into a property of your ViewModel. If you put a breakpoint in the setter it get's hit if you select something in the ComboBox.

For future questions you might ask please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and base your question on that accordingly. That would have saved a lot of time.

UPDATE 2:
Added INotifyPropertyChanged to ViewModel example

Comment: Thanks for your help Frank, but I was under the impression handling events would not fall into following the MVVM design pattern.  I have seen many posts of binding to a propety and when this value changes the property his the set.  
This is was doesnt seem to work
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130850/selection-changed-event-of-combobox-in-wpf-mvvm